# On Ubuntu 16.04 ATI/AMD gpu is burning?

Tags: 16.04, radeon

I just upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 16.04 and my [AMD/ATI] RV770 [Radeon HD 4850] is getting very hot : 104°C !! The fans are spinning at full speed all the time !!
The problem is that there is no activity on my PC : nothing is moving on the screen, there is 98% of Idle on CPU.

As I have a dual boot, if I boot windows on the same computer : all is getting back to normal : temperature and fan speed decrease

What should I do to not have my GPU burnt ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround by adding the kernel parameters `radeon.dpm=1 amdgpu.dpm=1`:

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (e.g. by running `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`) and change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 amdgpu.dpm=1"
```

After that, update GRUB configuration using

```
sudo update-grub
```

and `reboot` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I reworded your answer a bit and replaced complex commands (like using `vi` instead of `nano` or `grub-mkconfig` instead of `update-grub`) with simpler ones, so that new users may follow it more easily. Also you should use `sudo` instead of root shells. If you don't like the edit, you may roll it back, but I doubt that ;-)

Comment: fixed typo : admgpu to amdgpu